# How to compute an array and return a nested array of to numbers inside a parent array using vuejs/javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, foreach, v-for

My problem is computing an array and return a nested object array of to numbers inside using vuejs/javascript? I'm doing it via compute prop with vue js 2.
The array i'm initialy looping looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Bob", 
    "Points": [{"Lat": 2, "Lon": 3}, {"Lat": 4, "Lon": 5} ]}  
  },
  {
    "name": "John", 
    "Points": [{"Lat": 6, "Lon": 7}, {"Lat": 8, "Lon": 9} ]}  
  }
]
```

So Im trying to return smth like [{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}]

I'm trying to make it like this but it fails:

```
computed: {
    departureStops() {
      return this.stops.forEach((s) =>
        s["points"].forEach((dp) => {
          dp.Lat;
          console.log("dp.Lat", dp.Lat);
        })
      );
    },
  },
```

I'm expecting to return a nested object array of to numbers inside like

```
[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6],[7,8]]
```

Comment: `{2, 3}` isn’t valid syntax for an array or object.  Did you mean `{"Lat": 2, "Lon": 3}`?

Comment: Ok, pardon, I think it would be [ [1,2],[…] ]

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
computed: {
    departureStops() {
        return this.stops.reduce((points, stop) => {
            const stopPoints = stop["Points"].map(point => [point.Lat, point.Lon]); // Make your array of points for this stop
            return points.concat(stopPoints); // add all of them to the final array
        }, []);
    },
},
```

Or:

```
computed: {
    departureStops() {
        return this.stops.flatMap(stop => {
            // Transform each stop into its array of points
            return stop["Points"].map(point => [point.Lat, point.Lon]);
        });// And flatten the structure to an array of points
    },
},
```

For instance:

```js
const stops = [
  {
    "name": "Bob", 
    "Points": [{"Lat": 2, "Lon": 3}, {"Lat": 4, "Lon": 5} ] 
  },
  {
    "name": "John", 
    "Points": [{"Lat": 6, "Lon": 7}, {"Lat": 8, "Lon": 9} ]  
  }
];

const departureStops = stops.flatMap(stop => {
    return stop["Points"].map(point => [point.Lat, point.Lon]);
});

console.log(departureStops);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't return a value in `computed` function, because you use `forEach`. If you use like:

```
const stops = [
      {
        'name': 'Bob',
        'Points': [{ 'Lat': 2, 'Lon': 3 }, { 'Lat': 4, 'Lon': 5 } ],
      },
      {
        'name': 'John',
        'Points': [{ 'Lat': 6, 'Lon': 7 }, { 'Lat': 8, 'Lon': 9 } ],
      },
    ]
```

```js
departureStops() {
  const stop = [];
  this.test.forEach((s) => s['Points'].forEach((dp) => {
    stop.push([dp.Lat, dp.Lon]);
  }));
  return stop;
}
```

The result will be:

```
[ [ 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 6, 7 ], [ 8, 9 ] ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but that’s not exactly what I need… What if I would need to return [1,2],[3,4]…? Can I return dp.Lat and dp.Lon at a time with one iteration ? Thx in advance

Comment: I updated my answer forEach and push. Or you can just use reduce as mention in @Vivick in previous answer